# How to find the specific week number by date range from date in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have fiscal month, which has a different date range than current date range for each month.

i.e

```
Fiscal Month    Start Date - End Date
Dec-15          11/30/15 - 12/25/15
Jan-16          12/28/15 - 1/29/16
Feb-16          2/1/16 - 2/26/16
```

How can I find the week number in `dec-15` fiscal month from date: 12/14/2015?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine week in fiscal year in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/958642/determine-week-in-fiscal-year-in-excel)

Comment: Is the date `12/14/2015` already parsed? If so, can you use WEEKNUM function?

Comment: If I go with Weeknum function , it will take regular month then provide the week number. but If I provide 12/14/2015 then it has to provide as 3 because this date fall under Dec-15 [11/30/15 - 12/25/15] fiscal month.

Comment: Your fiscal months appear to have irregular numbers of days and missing days.  You will probably need something like a lookup table.

Comment: @Steven: There are irregularities in the dates in this problem.  I don't think the solutions in the proposed duplicate will apply.

Comment: Is this the week count in the month?  Or the week count in the fiscal year?

Answer (score 1):

To find the weeknumber in the fiscal month, using the fiscal month scheme you show above, try, with the date in question in A3:

```
=CEILING((A3+1-(A3-DAY(A3)+2-WEEKDAY(A3-DAY(A3))))/7,1)
```

Explanation:

It seems that your fiscal month starts on the Monday of the Mon-Sun week which contains the 1st of the month; and the fiscal month ends on the preceding Friday, leaving the Sat-Sun between the end of one fiscal month and the start of the next fiscal month undefined.

My formula does not check for the date being the intervening weekend, but would place a date on that weekend in the preceding week -- but that could be easily added if it is an issue.

The segments of the formula:

Last day of preceding month:

```
A3-DAY(A3)
```

First day of this month:

```
+1
```

General formula to compute a Day of the Week (DOW) such that it will be the closest on or before the target date (TD).  DOW:  Sun=1, Mon=2, ... Sat=6

```
=TD+1-WEEKDAY(TD+1-DOW)
```

To then compute the weeknumber, 
 - we take the difference between the start of the fiscal month and our given date.

- Add one (1) as the result would otherwise be zero based.
- Divide by 7 to compute weeks.
- Round up to the next highest integer.

If you needed to compute the weeknumber for the fiscal year, you would need to figure out the start of the year, and then perform the same operation.

Comment: Geez, this deserves +1 just for figuring out the wacky fiscal date scheme.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks. Hopefully I figured it out correctly :-)